# Reset index on table with Eloquent model

Tags: laravel

I am scratching my head to figure out why this legacy code supposedly will reset the indexes on a database table. Can you shed some light on it?

```
    $employee = new Employee();
    $employee->update([
        'recruited' => 0,
        'job_id' => null,
        'job_start_date' => null,
        'job_end_date' => null,
        'interviewed' => 0
    ]);
```

There are a corresponding Eloquent model called `Employee`.

Comment: what's the point of setting everything to null when setup a new model?

Comment: @WailanTirajoh: That is my question.

Comment: haha, know what you feel brother. It's kinda frustrating sometimes seeing someone's code when it just doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 0):

try to use :

```
DB::table('employees')->update([
        'recruited' => 0,
        'job_id' => null,
        'job_start_date' => null,
        'job_end_date' => null,
        'interviewed' => 0
]);
```

Comment: The question what the code does, not how to do it differently.

Comment: i think update all records in table employees with data given in the array